# downloading unicode fonts to PDF file using PHP and MySQL

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, unicode, fonts

We are developing a billing application to give receipts to customers using **PHP** and **MySQL**. Our application contains both English as well as unicode languages such as Kannada. We are trying to print / download the receipts as pdf but unable to print unicode characters.

We tried with pdfmake in client side as well as fpdf in server side but both fails to print unicode.

The sample code in fpdf as follows:

```
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('Baraha','','baraha.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Baraha','',35);
$pdf->Write(10,' cheluva kannaDa nADu');
$pdf->Output();
```

and output will be,

In Braraha font: [image: Baraha Kannada font]

In Lohit Font: [image: Lohit Kannada Font]

**NB:** The correct Kannada sentence is `ಚೆಲುವ ಕನ್ನಡ ನಾಡು` for `cheluva kannaDa nADu` when using `Baraha.ttf`

Also what is the best way to print receipt directly without web browser's default print preview window in php.

Comment: this might be helpful : http://suanfazu.com/t/fpdf-utf-8-encoding-how-to/11570/4

Comment: @yogesh84 will check and let you know.

Comment: Chrome, for one, does not come with a Kannada font.

Comment: @yogesh84 - That link says not to use utf8.  However, you must use utf8 to get Kannada.